# Ngnix rewrite "no input file specified"

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

Recently I use nginx, but i have a problem with rewriting.
When i go to the orginal url there is no problem, when i use the rewrited url and its no *.php There is no problem. But when i use the rewrited url with a php file i get the error: no input file specified.
I think the rewrited url go to php and php can't find it because its rewrited and not a real file.

This is my rewrite rule:

> location /folder {
>
> ```
>   if (!-e $request_filename){
>   rewrite ^/folder\/.*?\/(.*) /folder/$1 break;
>   
>   }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: can you add a sample URL and what the behaviour should be. What you have posted should serve you static files. For PHP you need to pass .php files to fastcgi (https://www.howtoforge.de/anleitung/installation-von-nginx-mit-php5-und-php-fpm-mit-mysql-unterstutzung-unter-ubuntu-11-10/) some more info would be helpful

Comment: First, i have already installed php,mysql etc. This is only the rewrite part. A sample: the url must be example.com/folder/(random)/afile.php when i do that i got the no input file error. But when i do example.com/folder/afile.php i got the correct file. But it must be the first url.

Comment: first of all: http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil maybe there are other ways to solve your problems. Let me propose a different solution

Answer (score 0):

You can probably simplify this by just using a different location path, then you can completely avoid the if statement.

This is untested and might need some tweaking, but the general idea should be clear

```
location ~ /folder\/.*?\/(.*).php$ {
    rewrite ^ /folder/$1 permanent;
}
```